# Is it possible to group data inside a formData in Typescript ? ie the form data returns as an object , can i have another object inside it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms

Is it possible to have an object inside the object Formdata in typescript ? like object of objects inside a formData. Or should we structure the Html so that it can render it like object of objects . Can anyone answer please ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried!